# How does SNS determine which origination number to use when sending a transactional SMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We are in the US. We currently have 5 origination numbers in our primary region ( `us-west-2`). We send SMS messages quite simply by using `.publish()` like this (in NodeJS lambda):

```js
var sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: "us-west-2" });
sns.publish({Message: "Your code is 123456", PhoneNumber: "+19705555555"});
```

From what I can tell, SNS has always used 1 of the 5 numbers to send messages to our test accounts.

We have recently registered 5 Toll Free Numbers to replace those (didn't really ask too many questions here: we had 5 numbers, we still want 5 numbers).
The problem is that we now want to turn one number off (remove it) and instead use one of the new TFN.

The question is: **How does SNS know to use the new TFN?**
We know some SDKs allow specifying the origination number (or at least the identity), but we would like to avoid hard-coding that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber and AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID parameters to choose specific origination identities if a particular Region has multiple origination numbers or sender IDs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).